# How to set duration/number of times to trigger a CSS animation - specifically for a flying image across screen

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I found a css code for a flying image across the screen from this website:
https://support.cargo.site/Make-an-Image-Fly-Across-the-Screen. I will also paste the code here for quick reference.

Currently, the image flies non-stop. How to make it fly only based on the number of times that we can set?

Here's the code for HTML:

```
<div class="flier">{image 1}</div>
```

Here's the code for CSS:

```
.flier {
    pointer-events: none;
}

.flier > * {
/* Adjust animation duration to change the element’s speed */
        animation: fly 50s linear infinite;
        pointer-events: none !important;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform: translateX(-120%) translateY(-120%) rotateZ(0);
    position: fixed;
    animation-delay: 1s;
    z-index: 999999;
}

 /* Keyframe values control where the element will begin
    and end its trajectory across the screen. Each rule
    represents a path the element follows across the screen. */


@keyframes fly {

    98.001%, 0% {
                display: block;
        transform: translateX(-200%) translateY(100vh) rotateZ(0deg)
    }

    15% {
        transform: translateX(100vw) translateY(-100%) rotateZ(180deg)
    }

    15.001%, 18% {
        transform: translateX(100vw) translateY(-30%) rotateZ(0deg)
    }

    40% {
        transform: translateX(-200%) translateY(3vh) rotateZ(-180deg)
    }

    40.001%, 43% {
        transform: translateX(-200%) translateY(-100%) rotateZ(-180deg)
    }

    65% {
        transform: translateX(100vw) translateY(50vh) rotateZ(0deg)
    }

    65.001%, 68% {
        transform: translateX(20vw) translateY(-200%) rotateZ(180deg)
    }

    95% {
        transform: translateX(10vw) translateY(100vh) rotateZ(0deg)
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

***Update: Issue solved! Just change the 'infinite' to a number.**

Comment: Have you looked at the animation setting in the CSS and tried changing the infinite to a specific number?

Comment: Yes, I did. Anyway, I just tried again and I just realised that the image flies a few times across the screen(considered 1 time). I thought it didn't work before. Thanks for answering!